# Button and .resw idea Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a button and I want the content to be loaded by its name from my .resw file. I know that I can change that in the page class or in a class but is it possible to do this in XAML as a default option?

My button:

```
<Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,480,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" Height="42" Foreground="#FF0E0E0E"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve. This is a xaml code:

```
<Button x:Uid="/Resources/btnRecive" Name="btnSync" Content="Recibir"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,480,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" Height="42" Foreground="#FF0E0E0E" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" Click="btnSync_Click"/>
```

And resw archive:

btnRecive.Content | Recibir

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Here you have given content in xaml itself as Content="Recibir". How it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: Because the command for use Resources is: x:Uid="/Resources/btnRecive"

Comment: Yes..That's the reason, but I am not able to see strings in designer, I think we cant see. Able to see on device. Thanks

Comment: But u create a Resources named btnRecive and add string value? :O

Comment: I am able to create that resource and string is showing in device but not in designer, do you have any solution on this?

Comment: Wow, it's strange... :S

Comment: Yaa..its very bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the x:Uid attribute which will look for a string in your resw file.

```
<Button x:Uid="SendButton" />
```

The key for the entry in your resw file should look like this:

```
SendButton.Content
```

You can also add a path to a resource file in case you have multiple files

```
<Button x:Uid="/Forms/SendButton"/>
```

The I18N system introduced with WinRT is totally flexible. I suggest reading the following article for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx

Comment: My idea it's use multilanguage on buttons with different .resw archives. This method doesn't work... :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added a sample with a path. You can use that to address other resources. Let me know if this works. I know all this works because I use it on a daily basis ;) If you need a specific scenario you need to give more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:yourNameSpace.Resources"

Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.YourResource}"
```

oops it's for WPF => check this link for WP8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: This is for windows phone 8, my windows phone is 8.1... :(

Comment: 8.1 silverlight or xaml?